# slider for my drag and drop lists

Tags: jquery

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/FCKvk/

When you pull an image from one of the lists in the other one it exstands the height of the div, i don't want that!

When the pictures are more than 4 on one list i want to aciev something like this:

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll

```
$(function(){
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

How can it be done? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the containers:

```
#sortable1, #sortable2 { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 0 2.5em; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLFzD/)